# Why this delegate method is not called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

Using protocols and delegates is not something that I'm using to often( I used it before), but this time, I thing that I did everything as it should be done but the method from protocol is not called.

So I have 2 classes: ToolBarViewController and Core and in ToolBarView I have 1 button. When I press the button it should call the method toolBarButton pressed from the ToolBarViewControllerDelegate. 
some code:

1) Protocol and delegate declaration in ToolBarViewController.h

```
@protocol ToolBarViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)toolBarButtonPressed:(NSString*)buttonName;

@end
```

.
.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ToolBarViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

2) Method call in ToolBarViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)button1:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"b1");
    if([ self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(toolBarButtonPressed:)]){
        [self.delegate toolBarButtonPressed:@"button1"];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"don't responde");
    }
}
```

3) Core using the ToolVarViewControllerDelegate in Core.h

```
@interface Core : NSObject<ToolBarViewControllerDelegate>
```

4) Instantiate the ToolBarViewController object and setting the delegate in Core.m

```
 -(id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self){
    toolBarViewController = [[ToolBarViewController alloc]init];
    [toolBarViewController setDelegate:self];
    self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Core Inited.........DONE");
}
return self;
```

}
5) The method toolBarButtonPressed: in Core.m

```
-(void)toolBarButtonPressed:(NSString*)buttonName{
    NSLog(@"Button pressed %@",buttonName);
}
```

6) ToolBarViewController declaration in core.h:

```
@property (strong) ToolBarViewController* toolBarViewController;
```

7) subview connections:
[image]
The interesting thing is that when the button is pressed that if is returning false.
Does anyone can explain why this is happening?
Thank You

Comment: Could you check if `self.delegate` is nil in the button click handler?

Comment: yes it is nil. But I don't understand why

Comment: I checked if the object toolBarViewController is nil after i set the delegate in core.m and it is not null. Then why the delegate in ToolBarViewController is nil?

Comment: So Core must have been deallocated

Comment: What do you do with `toolBarViewController` that you set the delegate on? Update your question with the code around those 2 lines.

Comment: Do you save the core object to a property or a collection?

Comment: Because you are not setting the delegate anywhere. You think you do set it but in reality you are creating a brand new object and set it's delegate.

Comment: @Desdenova Not necessarily. He could be presenting toolBarViewController after setting the delegate on it. I've asked the OP for the code surrounding that line.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I updated my question with the entire constructor from core.m where I declared the toolBarViewController and set it's delegate.

Comment: @vikingosegundo the core object is declared in appdelegate.h as a strong property.

Comment: Where does toolBarViewController come from? Is it in a storyboard/xib?

Comment: it's the controller for a custom view from the MainMenu.xib

Comment: Where is this button you refer to coming from? Is there a class called ToolBarView you haven't shown us?

Comment: it is in the same customview controlled by toolBarViewController and it is connected in ToolBarViewController.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line creates a brand new view controller. It does *not* get the one that's already in your view hierarchy.

```
toolBarViewController = [[ToolBarViewController alloc] init];
```

If the ToolBarViewController is already in your view hierarch you should be doing something like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.toolBarViewController setDelegate:self];
}
```

If it's *not* in your view hierarchy yet, it should look something like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toolBarViewController = [[ToolBarViewController alloc] init];
    [self.toolBarViewController setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolBarViewController.view];
}
```

Comment: Well the problem is that toolBarViewController is declared in Core.h as a strong property and in the line highlighted by you is first time initialized. If I delete that line then the toolBarViewObject will not be initialized anymore

Comment: How does ToolBarViewController get into the view hierarchy? Where does it get presented?

Comment: The program structure is: appdelegate declares and creates the core object the core class declares and creates toolbarviewcontroller and mainviewcontroller. toolbarviewcontroller and mainviewcontroller are controlling 2 subviews in the app's main window

Comment: Show the code where you present ToolBarViewController.

Comment: point 6) in question is the declaration then point 4 in question in the init function from core.m

Comment: probably  @vikingosegundo is right and my core object got dealloc but I can't figure why

Comment: That code doesn't tell us how ToolBarViewController gets into the view hierarchy.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what code you are asking me for. the connection from the ToolBarViewController and the custom view that it controls is mede from interface builder.

Comment: @user1792771 So you have an outlet! Where is that?

Comment: Well I don't have the outlet I used the ViewController object from interfacebuilder and I connected to the custom view check the screenshot

Comment: Create an outlet for the ToolBarViewController in your xib. `alloc init` creates a **brand new** object which is NOT the same one that is already wired up in your xib.

Comment: The strange thing the toolBarViewController object form core is at the memory address: 0x6080000d9b40 but the class's instance used when I press the button is at this address: 0x6000000d3710 . therefore I think that there are 2 instances of the same class used in my app but I didn't made the second one.

Comment: Now you get it! That's exactly what I've been trying to tell you. The one in the xib is **created for you**. This is the one that has it's view (the buttons) in the view hierarchy. The one you `alloc init` in code is a _completely different object_. This one does **not** have it's view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Well i made the iboutlet in core.h and I connected to the ToolBarViewController in interface builder then I synthesize it and I deleted the old alloc init line but now when I check the memory addresses in Core the toolBarViewController has address null

Comment: You shouldn't need to synthesize anything.

Comment: Are you checking it in `init`? The ToolBarViewController in your xib doesn't exist until `viewDidLoad`.